# Outlook in an Exchange Environment Not Showing Any Email On Fresh Profiles

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, outlook, outlook-2007

We have an Exchange 2003 environment with Outlook '07. When using OWA to connect to mailboxes everything works fine. If someone currently has their Outlook profile set up and their mail downloaded in cached mode, everything works fine.

However if they go to have a new Outlook profile set up (in cached mode or not, it doesn't matter) Outlook just opens and says its waiting to update folders and doesn't do anything - all their e-mail just sits there empty with a complete folder structure. It says 'Connected to Outlook' in the lower-right corner, though.

When we look on the Exchange server it's not showing any errors in the event log and no issues are apparent with anyone actively using e-mail.

We've fixed this on the couple people that we've had to set up on new computers by exporting their mailbox to PST, deleting their mailbox, recreating their mailbox, then putting it back - acting like it's a corrupt mailbox.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? There aren't really any errors or similar to indicate that something is actually up so it's difficult to get a starting point to troubleshoot.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Exchange 2007 has this option with backwards client compatibility. Do you have Outlook 2003 listed there?

Comment: I don't have a useful answer, but you can hold [control and right-click on the Outlook icon in the system tray](http://blog.tiensivu.com/aaron/archives/1398-Little-known-Outlook-feature-Hold-down-Ctrl,-right-click-on-tray-icon-Connection-Status-appears.html) to get a "Connection Status" dialog. This may aid in your troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before where Outlook gets confused with the offline (.ost) file being stored in the same place between profiles.  Try deleting any .ost files and resyncing to see if the mail comes in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately if we delete the profile / .ost / whatever it doesn't fix anything. We can even do it on different computers with brand new profiles and it doesn't work, so it seems to be server side.